# Jboss AS7 deployment error (Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit) using maven + hibernate + Spring Data JPA + Atmosphere

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss7.x, spring-data-jpa, atmosphere

I've been trying to resolve this issue for an entire day now. Can somebody please point me in the right direction to understand what I'm doing incorrectly?

The Application utilizes ***maven* + *hibernate* + *Spring Data JPA* + *Atmosphere* on *JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final***. On my former windows machine and even on Openshift the application got deployed using the following **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** (with Jboss modules), while other dependencies were resolved by **maven**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang3"></module>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"></module>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.fileupload"></module>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.digester"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.validator"/>
            <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents.latest"></module>
            <module name="org.apache.velocity17"></module>
            <module name="org.apache.velocity17.view"></module>
            <module name="org.jsoup"></module>
            <module name="org.quartz"></module>
            <module name="com.google.gson"></module>
            <module name="com.mongodb"></module>
            <module name="com.mysql"></module>
            <module name="com.thoughtworks.paranamer"></module>
            <module name="com.vanso.sxmp"></module>
            <module name="net.java.dev.jets3t"></module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

On my old computer I started moving all the Jboss Module dependencies to fully utilize Maven's pom.xml, So in my eclipse IDE, whenever I do ***Project Right Click Menu > Maven > Update Project...***, then run the Application, I started getting the following StackTrace;

---

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
09:14:26,025 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for app
09:14:26,478 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment app-1.0.war
09:14:26,541 INFO  [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension] (MSC service thread 1-6) Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
09:14:26,603 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component base.modules.views.AppDispatcherServlet due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: base.modules.views.AppDispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.app-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]

09:14:26,619 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component base.modules.atmosphere.AtmosphereFrameworkServletFacade due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: base.modules.atmosphere.AtmosphereFrameworkServletFacade from [Module "deployment.app-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]

09:14:26,775 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: app-1.0.war
09:14:26,806 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)
09:14:26,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'app-1.0.war#app'
09:14:26,994 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
09:14:27,009 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
09:14:27,009 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
09:14:27,009 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
09:14:27,025 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: app
    ...]
09:14:27,214 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."app-1.0.war#app": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."app-1.0.war#app": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: app] class or package not found
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1400)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1183)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: base.model.CardSetting from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @701b206f (roots: C:\jBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1389)
    ... 11 more

09:14:27,230 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:14:27,230 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 22084ms - Started 309 of 586 services (193 services failed or missing dependencies, 80 services are passive or on-demand)
09:14:27,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "app-1.0.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-1.0.war#app\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-1.0.war#app\": Failed to start service"}}
09:14:27,777 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment app-1.0.war in 331ms
09:14:27,777 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."app-1.0.war#app": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."app-1.0.war#app": Failed to start service

09:14:27,777 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-1.0.war#app\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"app-1.0.war#app\": Failed to start service"}}}}
```

---

However when I go to JBOSS_HOME/standalone folder and delete **'data'** and **'tmp'** folders then run `mvn clean install -U` from windows cmd, then the Application deploys and runs normally.

After some time, I eventually had to move to another computer. Now the project would never deploy anymore and I always get that Exception.

---

I currently have the following config for the application;

**jboss module** *(JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main/module.xml)*

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

---

**standalone.xml** *(data source subsystem)*

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/db_name" pool-name="pool_name" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://<db-url-here>:3306/db_name</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

---

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="app"> <!-- tratransaction-type="JTA" -->
        <class>base.model.CardSetting</class>
        <class>base.model.Circle</class>
        <!-- others omitted for brevity -->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:jboss/datasources/db_name"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

maven **pom.xml** (...the relevant parts)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-security</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.jpa.api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>javascript</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.0, )</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-websockets</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As you can see here, I have tried to exclude `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` just so it can use a separate hibernate from JBoss's native instance (i.e ``hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` that comes with hibernate 4.3.8), but yet to no avail.

---

The Erring Classes **->** `AppDispatcherServlet` and `AtmosphereFrameworkServletFacade` are respectively located in;

```
base.modules.views.AppDispatcherServlet
base.modules.atmosphere.AtmosphereFrameworkServletFacade
```

---

And in **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>base.modules.views.AppDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>base.modules.atmosphere.AtmosphereFrameworkServletFacade</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>base</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` so something is not packaged right (maybe wrong maven scope eg. provided) or there are some dependencies missing on the classpath

Comment: i've checkeed all the dependencies and nothing seems wrong... in fact running `mvn clean install -U` builds successfully with no error.

Comment: can u show us effective POM ?

Comment: I dont have enough characters left in the OP to post my effective POM... so I made a link here https://github.com/Olatunji-Longe/text-dropins/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Okay so it is all about missing `base.model.CardSetting` . Do you have it in your "main" module or some sort of submodule? If so, you have to include that submodule as project dependency as well.

Comment: Sure, I have all the classes in the main module... Actually the project is just one single module